# Multiple item dbset retrieval method

Tags: c#, controller

Is there a way to retrieve multiple single items from a dbset query. I'm trying to build a get multiplenumbereditems controller directive.

I take a string an convert it into an array of id's. I then sort the ids ascending.

I just don't know of a propper way to build my list or añ optimal dbset seek method that will sequentially take my id's and only return list built out of these items. Or is returning multiple single items my only option. My table is small enough to just grab them all but I want to build something now should the database grow.

The table has an auto generated I'd list and will stay sequential or am I making an assumption about speed here.

Any guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use the [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) method. For example, lets assume you have a list of ids like this:

```
var ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

You cn use that list directly like this:

```
var elements = context.Items.Where(i => ids.Contains(i.Id));
```